# Sub-modules within a Region in WPF Prism

Tags: wpf, mvvm, module, navigation, prism

I have 3 modules within my WPF application (Module A, B and C). However module C has sub-modules (C1, C2, ..., C5). In fact, module C it's only a "container" for its sub-modules, so I am not sure if module C it is actually a module. I am wondering what is the best design following the Prism approach. At the moment this is my solution schema:

**PrismModularApp**

```
- App.config
- App.xaml
- Bootstrapper.cs
- Shell.xaml
```

**PrismModularApp.Controls**

**PrismModularApp.Infrastructure**

```
- RegionNames.cs
```

**PrismModularApp.Modules.A**

```
- AViewModel.cs
- ANavigationItemView.xaml
- AView.xaml
- AModule.cs
```

**PrismModularApp.Modules.B**

```
- BViewModel.cs
- BNavigationItemView.xaml
- BView.xaml
- BModule.cs
```

**PrismModularApp.Modules.C**

```
- CViewModel.cs
- CNavigationItemView.xaml
- CView.xaml
- CModule.cs
```

My Shell has two regions: MainContentRegion and MainNavigationRegion:
[image]

Every module has 2 views (XNavigationItemView and XView) one for the MainNavigationRegion and the other one for the MainContentRegion

The module C (the one I told you it is a container for sub-modules C1, C2, ... C5) has an area in the MainContentRegion for sub-navigation between sub-modules C1, C2, ... C5:

[image]

So, what's the best approach for this solution? Any ideas?

Comment: There are no sub-modules in prism, are you confusing modules with regions and nested regions? If that is the case, you can have regions inside a view that's in a region itself (a region in another region is called a nested region)

Comment: Then, what you are saying is that in this case CView should have two regions and I can create projects (PrismModularApp.Modules.C.C1, PrismModularApp.Modules.C.C2,..., PrismModularApp.Modules.C.C3) that register views in CView regions as if CView it's a Shell itself?

Comment: Jup. Depending on the type of the region, one region can also host multiple views (think of a tab control, for example, or a (ribbon-)menu bar). That behaviour can be adapted to new kinds of regions using `RegionAdapter` implementations.

Comment: So then, it would be more appropiate if CView.xaml it named CShell.xaml instead, wouldn't it? Do I need a CBootstrapper.cs as well? And what will happen with the CViewModel.cs? What will be their responsabilities?

Comment: No, there's _one_ shell, the one that's created by the bootstrapper, and there's _one_ bootstrapper, the one that's created by the application.

Comment: Who is the responsible of registering the C1, C2,... C3 views and navigation views in the CView regions?

Comment: Each module makes its own part of the application known to the rest of the application, i.e. in your case, the module(s) containing C1, C2, ... should register them (in their `Initialize` method)

Comment: Thanks Haukinger. I did it and everything works fine except for one detail: CView.xaml.cs implements public void OnImportsSatisfied() which is rised when the module is imported (that's fine) but the region is not loaded. This is the code: this.ModuleManager.LoadModuleCompleted += (s, e) =>{  
                    if (e.ModuleInfo.ModuleName == C1ModuleName)
                    {
                        this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate(
                            RegionNames.CContentRegion,
                            C1ViewUri);
                    }
                };}