# Menu item in Navigation region (WPF Prism)

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a modular WPF Prism application as described in this question: [Sub-modules within a Region in WPF Prism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485593/sub-modules-within-a-region-in-wpf-prism?noredirect=1#comment68223935_40485593)

Every main module (A, B and C) registers a NavigationItemView in the NavigationRegion and an ItemView in the MainRegion. So whenever a NavitaionItemView is pressed, the corresponding ItemView is loaded in the MainRegion.

But now, I want to add a button in the NavigationRegion that is not a NavigationItemView so it has no associate ItemView loaded in the MainRegion; but instead, it is a Menu (with an image and some menu items). Something like this:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem ToolTip="Settings" Background="#D6D6DC" BorderBrush="#D6D6DC">
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="Images/settings2.png" Width="30" Height="30" />
            </StackPanel>
        </MenuItem.Header>
        <MenuItem Header="_Language">
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_English" IsCheckable="True" Header="English" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_Spanish" IsCheckable="True" Header="Spanish" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Header="Load file" x:Name="MenuItem_LoadFile" Click="LoadFile" />

    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

What is the best approach to do this within Prism framework? I am quite new to Prism, so the further details on how to organize the classes the better. Thanks in advance!

**Clarification:**

My Shell has two regions (NavigationRegion -which is a ToolBar- and MainContentRegion - which is a ContentControl-). Every module registers a ModuleNavigationView in the NavigationRegion and a ModuleView in the MainContentRegion. Whenever the ModuleNavigationView is pressed, the ModuleView is shown in the MainContentRegion.

I want to add another item (Menu) to the toolbar (just like the ModuleNavigationView's), but this one is a special one because it doesn't show anything in the MainContentRegion, but instead shows a menu with some options.

And my question is if this settings menu should be another Module. What's the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: You need to clarify the scenario, because it is not clear what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @BrianLagunas I have edited the post with more details. Thank you for your help